# Why is my code throwing an IOException on zip extract?

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, ioexception

I am using the DotNetZip library (the compact framework version) on a Windows CE app, using VB.Net. This seems to have worked before on CE 5.0; the problem is on CE 6.0. The Message of the exception object is simply "IOException occured" (not very specific, yes), and when I try to get the message from the InnerException, that itself throws a NullReferenceException.

Update: The error happens when the zip file contains an exe file, no problems with a text file.

Update (again): The problem isn't with the Zip library, it's with the exe (the one being copied over). I'm still finding why it's "in use". GetProcesses (OpenNetCF) doesn't have it on the list. Other exes, despite having run before, can be overwritten. Not this one, not once it's already run before.

Here is the code:

```
Using zip1 As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipToUnpack)
                Dim f As ZipEntry
                For Each f In zip1
                    f.Extract(TargetDir, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
                Next
            End Using
```

And this is the stack:

```
IOException

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync, 

String msgPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtract(String baseDir, Stream outstream, String password)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Extract(String baseDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction extractExistingFile)
   at updateMpad3.Form1.Timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer._WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationThreadContext._InternalContextMessages(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at updateMpad3.Form1.Main()
```

Comment: Can you add the value of the `Message` property of the IOException?

Comment: It simply says "IOException occured". Nothing in the InnerException.

I've found that the error happens when the zip contains an .exe file. Nothing when it's simply a text file.

Comment: Could you try writing some dummy data to `Path.Combine(TargetDir, "test.exe")` from within your application? Because this may not be specific to that zip library.

Comment: Combined path was "\Program Files\mpad3ce\test.exe". Were TargetDir and ZiptoUnpack what you wanted to see?

Comment: @Yves No I meant let your application write some dummy data to the destination path to see if that works - perhaps the problem has nothing to do with the zip library (since the stack trace indicates it fails at `System.IO.FileStream..ctor(...)`). The file may be in use, for instance.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Thank you! It was a permission/use thing. I tried the same exe, but renamed, and there was no error. New problem though: I can't find why the exe can't be overwritten. It /had/ been running, but I've tried a few ways to close it (Application.exit, form.Dispose). It doesn't /seem/ to be running, since with GetProcesses (with OpenNetCF)  the exe isn't on the list. I can overwrite the file if I copy over it through Windows Mobile Device Center. Any idea why it's somehow in use?

Comment: No I can't think of any other reason than it running. As a workaround you could rename the file (that _is_ allowed while it is running) but you'll end up with a `.old` file on your system.

Comment: Thanks again. It works now. It's odd because the zip library can't extract directly now, and I have to extract in My Documents and then copy over to Program Files. Zip To has worked in my tests with other files before.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I extracted in My Documents, renamed/moved the file to be overwritten, and copied the extracted file to Program Files (where the replaced exe should be).

I'm not really sure what caused it, though. Nothing could overwrite that one specific exe. DotNetZip couldn't extract directly to that specific exe's folder (even after renaming it; other exes worked fine), but File.Copy worked just fine.